# Diagonal of product of matrices, expression with inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. They are full and not square, though their dimensions implies that their product is :
$$
\dim (\mathbf{A}) = (n,p) \quad \text{and} \quad \dim (\mathbf{B}) = (p,n) \implies \dim (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})=(n,n)
$$

Now, I am interested in calculating the diagonal terms of this product, but without having to calculate all the other terms in the process (this will be in a code where $n$ and $p$ are very large). I wrote it on a simple example and ended up with :
$$
diag(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}) = \sum Col\left(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}^\mathsf{T} \right)
$$

with $\cdot$ the inner product between the two matrices, and $\sum Col$ the sum on the columns of the matrix. Sorry if my formalism is bad, I wrote it in a coding style, so please feel free to correct me.

I tested it on my code and it matches, but :

- How could I demonstrate that properly?
- Is there a theorem or a property for that? I failed to find it on the internet...

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @S. Dolan, I finally got the demonstration I was searching for. So in case others need it, here it is step by step.

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ two matrices such as:

$$\dim (\mathbf{A}) = (n,p) \quad \text{and} \quad \dim (\mathbf{B}) = (p,n)$$

As their dimensions match, their [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition) gives:

$$\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}= \sum_{k=1}^p a_{ik}b_{kj} \quad \forall i\in[1,n] \text{ and } \forall j\in[1,n]$$

were $a$ and $b$ are the elements of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. Taking only the diagonal terms of this product, hence the terms for which $i=j$, yields:

$$diag\left(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}\right)= \sum_{k=1}^p a_{ik}b_{ki} \quad \forall i\in[1,n]$$

Besides, their [dot/inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) $\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}^\mathsf{T}$ is the term-by-term product:
$$\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}^\mathsf{T} = a_{ik} b_{ki} \quad  \forall i\in[1,n] \text{ and } \forall k\in [1,p] $$

So that the sum on its columns (with index $k$) is:
$$\sum Col \left(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}^\mathsf{T}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^p a_{ik} b_{ki} \quad  \forall i\in[1,n] $$

It can then be concluded that:
$$diag\left(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}\right)= \sum Col \left(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}^\mathsf{T}\right)$$

*QED*

Answer (score 3):

The $i$th term on the diagonal is the scalar product of the $i$th row of $A$ with the transpose of the $i$th column of $B$. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could be, would you have a reference for that? I could dig in to tell you if this is what I seek. I did not even find a wikipedia page for the "diag" operator ^^"

Comment: This is basically just the definition of the matrix product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: Ok I already stated that $diag(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})=\left[\sum_{k=1}^p a_{ik} b_{ki} \right]_{i=1..n}$ (hope the formalism is ok here). I also have $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B} = \left[ a_{ik} b_{ik} \right]_{i=1..n \, , \, k=1..p}$, but I fail to see how to properly link the twos (like said I had to write it down... well I didn't say I was good at maths ^^)

Comment: Your diag(AB) result is fine. However  A.B. does **not ** give you this.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B}$ an element-wise multiplication? Hence : $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B} = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}b_{11} & a_{12}b_{12} & \dots \\ a_{21}b_{21} & a_{22}b_{22} & \dots \\ \dots & \dots & \dots\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Again my formalism can be wrong, I am more used to `python`'s notations, and `A@B` would be $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$ and `A*B` $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B}$, as far as I understand

Comment: Yes but you need to add elements like  $a_{12}b_{21}$, not $a_{21}b_{21}$

Comment: i.e. you need the two inner suffices to be the same for a matrix product.

Comment: well yes sorry, of course if I take the same matrices as in my question, I have to calculate $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B}^\mathsf{T}$ as stated, which gives then $[a_{ik}b_{ki}]_{i=1..n\, , \, k=1..p}$. Still, if I express that I need to take the sum on the columns, then see the $\sum$ outside the matrix, not inside, right? I think my key problem here is that I don't know how to write properly $\sum Col$ with indexes... Again, thank you for your great help and your patience!